# Why does the GitLab Graph only show commits and not Additions/Deletions?

Tags: git, graph, gitlab

From my previous projects I´m used to being able to check **Additions/Deletions** committed by every project member but now (new project) I only see the numbers of commits from every group member in the Graph section of GitLab. This, however, proves a bit pointless because even a oneliner can stand for one commit and doesn´t satisfy my information need.

Since this is a university project, it is essential to follow the overall contributions of every member to the project.

How can I change it to showing the actual Additions/Deletions numbers ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been removed starting from v7.4.0 of GitLab, due to bad performance.

[You can see the feature removal in this commit.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/20e0c9b132f1a7d12b156936114155c89d55b8cf)

Answer (score 10):

Even if you can't rely on Gitlab anymore to show you these stats, it is still possible to get them directly from the command line.

See: https://coderwall.com/p/pek-yg/git-statistics-for-repo-per-author

```
git log --shortstat --author="Optional" | grep -E "fil(e|es) changed" | awk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6} END {print "files changed: ", files, "lines inserted: ", inserted, "lines deleted: ", deleted }'
```

Comment: Corrected awk commandline, accounting for commits with insertions or deletions only, exluding merges and renames: `git log --shortstat --no-merges --find-renames --pretty="%H" --author="<author>" | grep -E "files? changed" | awk 'BEGIN {inserted=0; deleted=0} {commits+=1; files+=$1} $5~/^insertions?/ {inserted+=$4} $5~/^deletions?/ {deleted+=$4} $7~/^deletions?/ {deleted+=$6} END {print "commits:", commits, "* files changed:", files, "* insertions(+):", inserted, "* deletions(-):", deleted}'`

Comment: If merely interested in a summary, we could simplify the expressions for machine parsing, using the _--numstat_ option: `git log --numstat --no-merges --find-renames --pretty="%H" --author="<author>" | awk 'NF==1 {commits+=1} NF==3 {files+=1; inserted+=$1; deleted+=$2} END {print "commits:", commits, "* files changed:", files, "* insertions(+):", inserted, "* deletions(-):", deleted}'`. Though one issue is that _--numstat_ vs _--shortstat_ yield different results for the number of changed files, insertions and deletions. My guess is due to binary files or the number of context lines?